# Set anchor tag value from code behind

Tags: asp.net, html

I am using the anchor tag `<a runat="server" id="myAnchor" rel="">` and i want to set the `rel` value from my code behind.I can access the anchore tag in code behind but i haven't seen the property called **rel**.
Can any body suggest me what i have to do.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set any attribute on controls using the `.Attributes` property. You are not see any property called rel because you use a general html control bu just placing the runat="server" on the anchor, and this is not like the HyperLink control that include more specific properties.

Example

```
private void Page_Load()
{
    //Example 1
    myAnchor.Attributes.Add("rel", "relative");

    //Example 2
    myAnchor.Attributes["rel"] = "relative";

}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a9d6h4f.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you can use "Attributes",like this:

```
myAnchor.Attributes["rel"] = "...";
```